# Can conducting electrons in a metal be modeled at all as classical particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, plasma-physics

I have seen computational models that treat the highest energy electrons in a conducting metal as classical particles in a plasma, the ions being held in place with some sort of heuristic nearest-neighbor forces.  The developers of these models are smarter than I am so I assume they know what they are doing.  But I don't understand it.  How can particles that exist where quantum mechanics "reigns supreme" be modeled successfully as classical particles?

Answer (score 4):

> How can particles that exist where quantum mechanics "reigns supreme" be modeled successfully as classical particles?

If the model is useful, it gets wide popularity and sticks in physics irrespective of which framework - classical, probabilistic or quantum - it seems closest to.

The idea that the quantum theory is some kind of ultimate theory of matter all successful models can be reduced to is interesting, but it is not necessarily true. Even if it was, it would not be necessary for the classical models to work.

Models become successful for many reasons, but sometimes it is about gains/complexity ratio being high enough. Some classical models, such as the Lorentz-Drude model of conductivity/matter-EM wave interaction, have very high pedagogical and heuristic value and sticked well. There are alternative quantum models, but they are often either very similar (two-level system) or too complex (Schroedinger's equation for charged particles in external field) so when people need simple model to describe matter - EM field interaction, they often find one that is good enough  in this old proven model.

Answer (score 2):

The [Drude model (1900)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) is based on statistical mechanics plus Maxwell's electrodynamics as updated by Lorentz to include the electron and atoms.

It gives good results for some processes, such as conductivity/resistance of metals, but is way off on others, such heat capacity, and totally ignores important features such as band structure.

The [semi-classical Free Electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model), developed by Sommerfeld, an extension of the Drude model, fixes some of these problems; as pointed out in the comments.

Thus there are many models, but as with all modeling, the user must be aware of its realm of applicability and its limitations.

Comment: for many purposes we can incorporate the band structure by changing $m\to m^*$, right?

Comment: For some purposes in the most simple metals, maybe.